# m_pTransform->ProcessInput(0, pInputSample, 0) fails

Tags: c++, video, webcam, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to access the USB web with MJPG format in Media Foundation. for  decoding the buffer sample i'm using the MFT intel hardware.

```
hr = m_pTransform->ProcessInput(0, pInputSample, 0);
```

this process input API throws the error code 0xc00d36b5.

I need to know what causes the error.

Comment: How do you check the error code? What does it mean that the API "throws" an error? And can you please try to create a [mre] to show us?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mftransform/nf-mftransform-imftransform-processinput) say that `0xc00d36b5 = MF_E_NOTACCEPTING` or "The transform cannot process more input at this time." and

> If the MFT already has enough input data to produce an output sample, it does not accept new input data, and ProcessInput returns `MF_E_NOTACCEPTING`. At that point, the client should clear the pending input data by doing one of the following:
>
> - Generate new output by calling IMFTransform::ProcessOutput.
> - Flush the input data by calling IMFTransform::ProcessMessage with the MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH message.

So you probably need to call or keep calling `ProcessOutput()` to get your decoded buffer(s).